# Verifying that $f(x) \leq Cg(x)$ for $x \geq k$

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics

I'm revising for a test and having problems with a past question. It states that $f(x)=5x^2+4x+3$ is $O(x^2)$ and has a series of sub-parts asking if particular values of $C$ and $k$ (e.g., $C=12$, $k=0$) are witnesses of this fact (i.e., $f(x)\leq Cx^2$ for all $x>k$).

My method so far has been to establish some "test scenarios" / cases for each pair of witnesses. E.g., for $C=12$, $k=0$, I need to verify that
$|5x^2 + 4x + 3| \leq 12|x^2|$ for $x > 0$.

In this case my method has been to test for  $x = 0$, which is true and some other arbitrary values $x> 0$. It seems to me that this may cause errors, because I'm only checking cases instead of actually proving it.

For example, for $C=12$, $k=1$, I got the wrong answer answer because
$f(x) > x^2$ for $x \approx 1.2$ and I did not check for that x-values in that area.

Any suggestions for a bulletproof method for questions like these?
Could I do it by induction?

Comment: Bulletproof?  find the roots of $Cx^2 - f(x)$ and make sure k is beyond the rightmost root.